# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}i^{n(n+1)}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

How to analyse the convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}i^{n(n+1)}=1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}+\dots?$$

I've thought about using results about alternating series but this one is not exactly of one those.  I've also tried to show that the sequence of partial sums is a Cauchy sequence and then to find a convergent subsequence of them, but I wasn't successful either.

Remark: I even know this series is really convergent...

Comment: Add two and two terms together, and you get an alternating series.

Comment: @Arthur But why can I do this? By doing this, I am considering a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums, right? Why the convergence of this subsequence would imply the convergence of the sequence of partial sums, i.e. the series?

Comment: It's true that it requires care, and isn't always valid, but Robert explains it nicely in the post below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that for any positive integer $N$,
$$S_{2N+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}i^{n(n+1)}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right).$$
Moreover $S_{2N}=S_{2N+1}-\frac{(-1)^N}{2N+1}$ which implies that if $S_{2N+1}\to L$ then $S_{2N}\to L$ too. Hence the series is convergent by Leibniz.

Once convergence is established, it follows that
\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}i^{n(n+1)}&=\lim_{N\to +\infty} S_{2N+1}=
\lim_{N\to +\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}
+\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}
+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=-\frac{\ln(2)}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I know that $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{2n} = -\frac{\ln(2)}{2}$ and $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} = \frac{\pi}{4}$, but how can we split this sum into these two sequences with confidence that we're not doing anything wrong?

Comment: Split the partial sum and then take the limit.

Comment: But the partial sums for these sequences are monsters I could never derive...

Comment: I mean
$$S_{2N+1}=1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$ and then take the limit as $n\to \infty$. Recall the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ and $\arctan(x)$.

Comment: @orlp $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x^n = \frac{1-x^N}{1-x},\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}= \int_0^x \frac{1-y^N}{1-y}dy = -\log(1-x)- \int_0^x \frac{y^N}{1-y}dy$. If $|x| = 1, x \ne 1$ then everything is well-defined and converges as $N \to \infty$, and it gives the closed-form for OP's series